# Error occurred while implement livekit_client: ^0.5.9 package #flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':livekit_client'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\livekit_client-0.5.9\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':livekit_client' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':flutter_webrtc'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':device_info_plus'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':livekit_client' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

```html
**Flutter version**
PS D:\AndroidStudioProjects\git_repo\talky> flutter --version
Flutter 2.10.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5464c5bac7 (3 weeks ago) • 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
Engine • revision 57d3bac3dd
Tools • Dart 2.16.2 • DevTools 2.9.2
PS D:\AndroidStudioProjects\git_repo\talky>



**AndroidMainfest.xml**

required permissions +
<application
    .....
    .....
 <service    
android:name="de.julianassmann.flutter_background.IsolateHolderService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection" />
    </application>


**Kotlin version - 1.6.10
Project level Build gradle
Dependency
**

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

flutter clean,pub get,invalidcash restart not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved my problem by following the below method:

remove the problem making package from
/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org

Run flutter pub get
change this:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
to this:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
and then in project-folder/buil.gradle

change this:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
to this:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
and then run this command

flutter clean

build or run your project. In this version livekit_client : ^0.5.9 android gradle has been updated. thats why we need to update android project gradle to 4.1.1.

good luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).